# Filtering a list based on Optional property in Scala

Tags: scala

Imagine I have the following list where `Tuple` second arg is optional

```
List(Tuple("FullName", Some(1)), Tuple("FullName", None))
```

What is the cleanest approach to get the following result?

```
List(Tuple("FullName", 1))
```

I could try

```
list.filter(_._2.isDefined).map((_._1, _._2.get))
```

I need to filter out all Tuples where the 2nd argument is `None` and then change the tuple type to contain a defined `integer` and not an `option`.

I was wondering if there is a prettier way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `collect` and pattern matching.

```
val list = List(("FullName", Some(1)), ("FullName", None))

scala> list collect { case (name, Some(i)) => (name, i) }
res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((FullName,1))
```

`collect` allows you to provide a partial function that will keep any values that are defined within the partial function, and discard any that are not.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that doesn't use `get()` might be

```
val list = List(("FullName", Some(1)), ("FullName", None))

list.filter(_._2.isDefined).unzip match {
  case (k, v) => k zip v.flatten
}
```